# Салат из редьки дайкон или из редьки дайкона?

Tags: склонение

Салат из редьки дайкон или из редьки дайкона?

Answer (score 0):

Названия сортов редьки не относятся к общеупотребительным словам, поэтому лучше бы в начальной форме.

Comment: Разве дело в употребительности слов?  А если слова общеупотребительные? Из рыбы карп или рыбы карпа?

Comment: Из профессии художник или из профессии художника?

Comment: Филе из рыбы карпа. Правда, так никто не пишет, но уж если, то вот так. Из профессии художника. Фразу придумать затрудняюсь.

Comment: Я задал отдельный вопрос на эту тему: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444738/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-2